# Google Domain Root domain forward to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns-hosting, dns-zone, google

I am trying to forward my root domain (minus www) to an S3 bucket using Google Domains. I get an error saying that it cannot forward root domain, is there a way I can do this? Is there a way I can find S3 ip address to forward to that?

Comment: You can only do this on Route 53. Redirect your site to www, instead.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without Route 53? I don't want to transfer my domain.

Comment: Read the rest of my previous comment.